# How to identify string is containing only number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdstring, alphabet

How to print only text in a string? I want to print only `abc` from.

```
string numtext = "abc123";
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    string text = "abc123";

    if (text.matches("[a-zA-Z]") //get an error initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
    {
        printf("%s", text);
    }
    getch();
}
```

My string contains both numbers and letters and I want to print letters only. But I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `std::string` has no member called `matches`, just in case if you don't know.

Comment: A very rough and expensive solution: `try` to convert it to a number type and `catch` an error.

Comment: @JeJo what do you mean?? means namespace missing in my program??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no member function called `std::string::matches` [available in the standard string library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for this case.

Secondly, The title of the question does not match the question you have asked with the code. However, I will try to deal with both. ;)

---

> How to print only text in a string?

You could simply print each element in the string(i.e. `char` s) if it is an alphabet while iterating through it. The checking can be done using the standard function called [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha), from the header `<cctype>`. **([See live example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CzXKsvgzHatkNI8F))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> // std::isalpha

int main()
{
    std::string text = "abc123";

    for(const char character : text)
        if (std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(character)))
            std::cout << character;
}
```

**Output**:

```
abc
```

---

> How to identify string is containing **only number**?

Provide a function which checks for all the characters in the string whether they are digits. You can use, standard algorithm [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) (needs header `<algorithm>` to be included) along with [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) (from `<cctype>` header) for this. **([See live example online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zu97ID8mDyP0Qop8))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::all_of
#include <cctype>    // std::isdigit
#include <iterator>  // std::cbegin, std::cend()

bool contains_only_numbers(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::all_of(std::cbegin(str), std::cend(str),
        [](char charector) {return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(charector)); });
}

int main()
{
    std::string text = "abc123";
    if (contains_only_numbers(text))
        std::cout << "String contains only numbers\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "String contains non-numbers as well\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
String contains non-numbers as well
```

Comment: I edited and made a small change. in case of `isalpha()`, input **must** cast to `unsigned char`. It is stated in here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: contains_only_numbers("-22.0e-6")

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `find_last_not_of` function of `std::string` and the create a `substr`

```
std::string numtext = "abc123"; 
size_t last_character = numtext.find_last_not_of("0123456789");
std::string output = numtext.substr(0, last_character + 1);
```

This solution just presumes that `numtext` always has a pattern of `text+num`, means something like `ab1c23` would give `output = "ab"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++ standard `regex` for such scenarios is a good idea. You can customize a lot.

Below is a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{

    std::regex re("[a-zA-Z]+");

    std::cmatch m;//TO COLLECT THE OUTPUT
    std::regex_search("abc123",m,re);


   //PRINT THE RESULT 
    std::cout << m[0] << '\n';
}
```